# Why is help(activeLayer()) not working?

Tags: pyqgis, syntax, nameerror

Why are neither of the commands below returning details on the active layer method?

It works when I use the class iface.

```
help(activeLayer)
help(activeLayer())
```

This is the error I get

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
> exec(code, self.locals)
> File "", line 1, in 
> NameError: name 'activeLayer' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

This is because Python doesn't have `activeLayer` imported into the current namespace, so it can't find it. Its not just the help that doesn't work, nothing will find `activeLayer`:

[image]

It finds `iface` because that is imported for you.

[image]

You can do `dir()` to see what is imported. You can do `dir(iface)` to see what the `iface` object has for you.

So to get the help on the `activeLayer` object, you can do `help(iface.activeLayer)` since `activeLayer` is a property of `iface` and `iface` is imported.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that helped allot

Comment: @ChaceCarpenter If you like the answer and it was helpful, please consider upvoting by clicking on the arrows next to the score and/or marking it as the accepted answer by clicking on the checkmark ✓.